# How to Open a new window in aspnet

Tags: asp.net

What is the code for Opening a web page in new Window?

My click event will do some process and I have to open to a new window
How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window.open and initiate your pop up

Study this article for a detailed know how:
[New Window](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=143380)